# Unity C# countdown to persist through scenes

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, static-classes

Hi I have a C# script written which I can then call inside another script to keep track of the amount of time remaining between different scenes, and then load a scene when the timer reaches 0. I beleive that both scripts are written correctly, but there is no action when the timer reaches 0, I think the issue is that I'm not placing the code in the correct location but I'm not really sure, I've tried adding it to both my start function and my update function.

Here is the script for the static class;

```
public static class GlobalCountDown
{
    static DateTime TimeStarted;
    static TimeSpan TotalTime;

    public static void StartCountDown(TimeSpan totalTime)
    {
        TimeStarted = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TotalTime = totalTime;
    }

    public static TimeSpan TimeLeft
    {
        get
        {
            var result = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeStarted;
            if (result.TotalSeconds <= 0)
                SceneManager.LoadScene("Lose");
                return TimeSpan.Zero;           
                //return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the call I make in each game scene to check the time remaining;

```
GlobalCountDown.StartCountDown (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (5));
```

I get a warning when compiling the script 'The private field `GlobalCountDown.TotalTime' is assigned but its value is never used' but am not sure how to fix it.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
var result = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeStarted;
```

To this

```
var result = TotalTime - (DateTime.UtcNow - TimeStarted);
```

In your behaviour do this

```
void Start() 
{
  GlobalCountDown.StartCountDown (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (5)); 
}

void Update() 
{
    if (GlobalCountDown.TimeLeft == TimeSpan.Zero)
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Lose");  
}
```

and remove the SceneManager code from your GlobalCountDown class